# iOS - How to pass build params in fastlane snapshot

Tags: xcodebuild, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I am using fastlane snapshot tool for taking snapshot for app screens.

According to fastlane community, i need to run,

```
fastlane snapshot init
```

Then after configuring project ui test target, i need to run

```
fastlane snapshot
```

But if I want to provide some build parameters like, xcodebuild test test-only params, how can I do that. For example i want to build like,

```
xcodebuild test -workspace <path>
                -scheme <name>
                -destination <specifier>
                -only-testing:TestBundleA/TestSuiteA/TestCaseA
                -only-testing:TestBundleB/TestSuiteB
                -only-testing:TestBundleC
```

I see,

```
fastlane snapshot --help
```

[image]

Then I added in Snapfile,

```
xcargs -only-testing:TestBundleB/TestSuiteB
```

But this gives error

> (eval):36: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or
>   '{' or '(' only-testing:TestBundleB/TestSuiteB

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with running snapshot from the command line, so if you can, I would recommend creating a fastlane/Fastfile (or editing it if it already exists) to have a lane that calls `snapshot` with the options that you are looking for. You can call it with its various parameters as explained in the [docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#screenshots)

The example shows you how `snapshot` could be called, and the Parameters table describes the other parameters you can pass to the fastlane Action.

To pass `xcargs` via the Snapfile, try `xcargs "-only-testing:TestBundleB/TestSuiteB"` in your Snapfile. See this [Issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/7261).

Comment: I tried with other param but failed. Can u plz give me a sample? How to run specific testcase only when uitest is running for snapshot?

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried so I have some context?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan I responded to your question in my response

Comment: i will check n let u know the result. Thanks.

Comment: Any luck using the quotes?

Comment: I am glad that I could help!